# Is there a way to tell if the sdcard is mounted vs not installed at all?

Tags: android, sd-card

Using the [api logic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) you can detect if the sd card is available for read or write, but it doesn't tell you why it is not writable.

I want to know if the user even has a sd card vs if it just mounted.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell if the sdcard is mounted in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902089/how-to-tell-if-the-sdcard-is-mounted-in-android) - Specifically, the accepted answer shows a method that does it.

Comment: I did see that one, but MEDIA_MOUNTED refers to the card being mounted to the device.  The language is a little confusing.  I am looking for a way to tell the difference between mounted to the device (available to read/write), mounted to something external like a computer (not available) and the phone not having a card at all (also not available).   Since I posted this question I noticed there are some other constants available here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html one of them being MEDIA_REMOVED.  I believe that one will do what I am looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for example:

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {

}
```

Check out the possible constants at : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29

Answer (score 6):

```
public static boolean isSdPresent() {

return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

}
```