# USB Mount Receiver invoking only when boot complete

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I'm stuck while working with `BroadCastReceiver` in which it is invoking only when device is powered on or restarted. I am connecting the USB device using OTG cable. Android system showing USB inserted icon every time but my app not receiving any event.

Let me know what wrong I'm doing.

I am having an application which only has a `BroadcastReceiver` as below.

```
public class MountReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = MountReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String actionName = intent.getAction();
    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext()
            , "on Receive", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    extractAllDataFromIntent(intent, context);
    boolean isMounted;
    if (actionName.equals("android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED")) {
        isMounted = true;
    } else {
        // actionName.equals("android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED"
        isMounted = false;
    }
}

private void extractAllDataFromIntent(Intent intent, Context context) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
        Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
        Log.e(TAG, "Dumping Intent start");
        StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
        msg.append(TAG + " Seprate app");
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next();
            Log.e(TAG, "[" + key + "=" + bundle.get(key) + "]");
            msg.append("[" + key + "=" + bundle.get(key) + "]");
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Dumping Intent end");
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext()
                , msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

I have manifest entry for this receiver as follows.

```
  <receiver
        android:name="com.example.manmohan.mountreceiverdemo.MountReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL" />

            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

A weird case I see is that receiver is receiving WiFi change events when added WiFi state change callbacks, but still no USB events are getting received.

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to know the external storage is mounted or not at any given point of time:

[Is there a way to tell if the sdcard is mounted vs not installed at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878903/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-the-sdcard-is-mounted-vs-not-installed-at-all)

You have clubbed all the actions together for one receiver. Try keeping separate receiver for each action, and check whether you can see the difference.

I believe you have added a permission in your manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />`

Comment: firstly i added only mount/unmount receiver action and then added rest in multiple transaction.

Comment: I want to read USB in android device and i can see that system is able to see it in OTG supported devices