# Check SDCARD all possible state android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

How can i check all possible state of SDCARD on android phone like ?

1. SDCARD mounted via the USB cable
2. SDCARD is installed
3. SDCARD have authority to read and write. if card is not mounted through USB cable.
4. SDCARD have authority to read and write. if card is mounted through USB cable.
5. SDCARD available size.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the state, you can use this instruction:

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
```

Then, for example, if you want to check if the SDCARD is mounted :

```
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
```

You can find further information in [the Android documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)

There is a nice SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902089/how-to-tell-if-the-sdcard-is-mounted-in-android) talking about detecting mounted sd card via USB..
Regards.

Comment: Do we have any way to check. How many SDcard we have in phone?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html to get SDCARD state

And refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html to get SDCARD available size.