# Mount sdcard programmatically in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tell if the sdcard is mounted in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902089/how-to-tell-if-the-sdcard-is-mounted-in-android)

can any one tel me about how to mount a SD CARD from code. I got following information from android google blog but not cleared.

the Settings app simply uses the AIDL Interface to the 
mount service via IMountService and calls mount.

And com.android.server.MountService sends the notifications.

The mountVolume call has this check inside : 
validatePermission(android.Manifest.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS);

The MountService then communicates using the NativeDaemonConnector via 
sockets 
but i am not cleared about why socket is created? and how NativeDaemonConnector communicates to VOLD.?