# Video does not play from SD card

Tags: android, video

I try to play a video from SD card.Thats why i try this code

```
public class VideoPlayActivity extends Activity {
private VideoView video;
private MediaController ctlr;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

File clip=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                   "haha.mp4");


if (clip.exists()) {
  video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
  video.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());

  ctlr=new MediaController(this);
  ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
  video.setMediaController(ctlr);
  video.requestFocus();
  video.start();
}
}
}
```

While i run this code in android device the video not display just the black screen.When i disconnect my phone and open this project the video play .What is actual problem inside the code?

Comment: when you connect your device sdcard will unmounted internally. But disconnect your device sdcard will mounted automatically. So, if your device is connected to PC then your code could not find sdcard.

Comment: As gtumca said, the SD card isn't mounted.  You'll need to turn off the USB drive feature. In your code, you really should be checking for the state of the SD card.  Many google results similar:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902089/how-to-tell-if-the-sdcard-is-mounted-in-android

Comment: This is not all about sd card mounting.I solve the problem.I use `<VideoView 
     android:id="@+id/video" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />` while previously i used `match_parent`