# Android SD Card detection error

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have this code, that should be executed, when SD card is removed from an Android device (by remove, I understand, that user selects `remove` from Android device menu or configuration, just as you remove  USB device or SD card from any other system, before phisically removing the card):

```
public void kartkontrol()
{
    String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    {
        // We can read and write the media
        Durum=" Hafıza Kartı Var    (Okuma/Yazma)";

    }
    else if (android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state))
    {
        // We can only read the media
        Durum=" Hafıza Kartı Var     (Okuma İzni)";
    }
    else
    {
        // No external media

        Durum=" Hafıza Kartı Yok";
    }
}
```

Card should be uninstalled and removed, but it seems, that it is actually installed during this process.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code when I remove the card is mounted, but it must be unmounted. I solved this problem with another code. running smoothly. no problem

```
    sSDpath = null;
        fileCur = null;


for (String sPathCur : Arrays.asList("ext_card", "external_sd", "ext_sd", "external","extSdCard", "externalSdCard")) // external sdcard
        {
            fileCur = new File("/mnt/", sPathCur);
            if (fileCur.isDirectory() && fileCur.canWrite()) {
                sSDpath = fileCur.getAbsolutePath();

                kartk.setText("Hafıza Kartı Takılı");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "kkkBirinci", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
        fileCur = null;
        if (sSDpath == null) {

            sSDpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

            kartk.setText("Hafıza Kartı Takılı Değil");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "kkkikinci", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find further information in the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html).

There is a nice [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902089/how-to-tell-if-the-sdcard-is-mounted-in-android) here talking about detecting mounted sd card via USB.

you can also use this useful method instead :

```
static public boolean hasStorage(boolean requireWriteAccess) {
    //TODO: After fix the bug,  add "if (VERBOSE)" before logging errors.
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    Log.v(TAG, "storage state is " + state);

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        if (requireWriteAccess) {
            boolean writable = checkFsWritable();
            Log.v(TAG, "storage writable is " + writable);
            return writable;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else if (!requireWriteAccess && Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```